# Error: Instance member cannot be used on type viewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

I get this error,

Instance member 'setPlacesAnnotations' cannot be used on type 'MapViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

on the lines

mapViewController.setPlacesAnnotations(), mapViewController.setBuildingsAnnotations(), and mapViewController.setRecreationAnnotations().

How would I fix this so that the code runs? The main objective of this code is to have a user click on a cell in a collection view and then to have that put annotations on the map based off of the selected cell category.

Here is my code for the collection view.

```
class ContentViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "1"), UIImage(named: "2"), UIImage(named: "3")]
let imageNameArray = ["Image 1", "Image 2", "Image 3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.mapIconImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.mapIconLabel.text! = imageNameArray[indexPath.row]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch (indexPath.item) {
    case 0: MapViewController.setPlacesOfWorshipAnnotations()
    case 1: MapViewController.setOrganizationsAnnotations()
    case 2: MapViewController.setGroceriesAnnotations()
}
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var mapIconImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var mapIconLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Here is the code for my map view.

```
struct PlacesOnMap {
var name: String
var latitude: Double
var longitude: Double

init(name: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    self.name = name
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
}
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

var places = [PlacesOnMap(name: "place 1", latitude: 28.551700, longitude: -81.374800),
    PlacesOnMap(name: "place 2", latitude: 28.553018, longitude: -81.374206),
    PlacesOnMap(name: "place 3", latitude: 28.553019, longitude: -81.367839)
    ]
var buildings = [PlacesOnMap(name: "place 1", latitude: 28.556969, longitude: -81.364319),
    PlacesOnMap(name: "place 2", latitude: 28.558126, longitude: -81.364725)
    ]
var recreation = [PlacesOnMap(name: "place 1", latitude: 28.54693, longitude: -81.393071),
    PlacesOnMap(name: "place 2", latitude: 28.538523, longitude: -81.385399),
    PlacesOnMap(name: "place 3", latitude: 28.542817, longitude: -81.378117),
    PlacesOnMap(name: "place 4", latitude: 28.538985, longitude: -81.404694)
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func setPlacesAnnotations() {
    let places = places.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
        let place = MKPointAnnotation()
        place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
        place.title = placeOnMap.name
        return place
    }
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    mapView.addAnnotations(places)
}

func setBuildingsAnnotations() {
    let places = buildings.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
        let place = MKPointAnnotation()
        place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
        place.title = placeOnMap.name
        return place
    }
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    mapView.addAnnotations(places)
}

func setRecreationAnnotations() {
    let places = recreation.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
        let place = MKPointAnnotation()
        place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
        place.title = placeOnMap.name
        return place
    }
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    mapView.addAnnotations(places)
}
```

[image: storyboard]

Answer (score 1):

As the error tells you, `MapViewController` is a type, it isn't an instance of `MapViewController` - The Swift convention of using capital letters for types and lower case letters for variables helps you spot these kinds of errors too.

You don't appear to have an instance of `MapViewController` in your `ContentViewController`, so I am not sure which map you wanted to add the annotations to.

Perhaps you want to present a new `MapViewController` when the user selects a cell?  Perhaps the map is already displayed in some other place?

You need your `ContentViewController` to have a reference to your `MapViewController` *instance*, wherever that is, in order to call the function to set the annotations.

If you are presenting a new controller then you would use a segue and set the annotations in `prepare(for:)`.

Comment: Thanks. How would I add a reference to my MapViewController instance for my ContentViewController?

Comment: You wouldn't normally add another view controller to the view controller (you can, it's called view controller containment, but it is probably more advanced that what you are after). You could add a map view to the current view controller in the storyboard or you could segue to a new view controller as I described in my edit